# Castle Windsor: Register two interfaces as one singleton with interception

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, castle

Following my previous question regarding Unity ( [Unity: Register two interfaces as one singleton with interception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367594/unity-register-two-interfaces-as-one-singleton-with-interception) ), I tried to do the same with Castle Windsor:

I have a class that implements two interfaces, and I want to apply interception to the class's methods. I'm using forwarded types to do this and have come up with the following code:

```
public interface I1
{
    void Method1();
}

public interface I2
{
    void Method2();
}

public class C : I1, I2
{
    public void Method1() {}
    public void Method2() {}
}

public class LogInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entering " + invocation.Method.Name);
        invocation.Proceed();
        Console.WriteLine("Leaving " + invocation.Method.Name);
    }
}

public static void CastleWindsorTest()
{
    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Register(
        Component.For<LogInterceptor>(),
        Component.For<I2, I1>().ImplementedBy<C>()
            .Interceptors(new InterceptorReference(typeof(LogInterceptor))).First
        );

    container.Resolve<I2>().Method2();
    container.Resolve<I1>().Method1();
}
```

The above code leads to the following output:

```
Entering Method2
Leaving Method2

Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.I2Proxy' to type 'I1'.
at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Resolve[T]() in e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Windsor\src\Castle.Windsor\Windsor\WindsorContainer.cs:line 872
at BlahMain.Program.CastleWindsorTest()
at BlahMain.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Removing the ".Interceptors" line causes the code to run without problems (but of course my interception code is not invoked). If I remove the ".Interceptors" line and instead decorate class C with "[Interceptor(typeof(LogInterceptor))]", I get the same output as above (i.e. Entering/Leaving Method2, followed by the exception).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: The latest one that I found: 2.5.3.

Comment: That's odd. Your code looks fine, I think it should work. I'll investigate later at home

Comment: What if you add the class as a service too? You may have to specify it as the first one for this to work

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood what you meant. I tried to use:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Register(
        Component.For<LogInterceptor>(),
        Component.For<C, I2, I1>().ImplementedBy<C>()
            .Interceptors(new InterceptorReference(typeof(LogInterceptor))).First
        );

    container.Resolve<I2>().Method2();
    container.Resolve<I1>().Method1();
```

Now the application doesn't crash with an exception, but my logging code is not called. The output I get is:

```
Method2 0
Method1 2
```