# How can I register one singleton to different interfaces in unity, XML config?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

How to do it in code is explained here:
[Unity Register two interfaces as one singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394650/unity-register-two-interfaces-as-one-singleton)

```
_container.RegisterType<EventService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
_container.RegisterType<IEventService, EventService>();
_container.RegisterType<IEventServiceInformation, EventService>();

bool singleton = ReferenceEquals(_container.Resolve<IEventService>(),   _container.Resolve<IEventServiceInformation>());
```

How to do it in the XML config?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Personally I like to spell out namespaces and assemblies in aliases. So xml:

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">

    <alias alias="Event_Interface" type="Mynamespace.IEventService, MyAssembly"/>
    <alias alias="EventService_Interface" type="Mynamespace.IEventServiceInformation, MyAssembly"/>
    <alias alias="Event_Class" type="Mynamespace.EventService, MyAssembly"/>

    <container>
      <register type="Event_Interface" mapTo="Event_Class"> 
        <lifetime type="singleton"/>
      </register>
      <register type="EventService_Interface" mapTo="Event_Class"> 
        <lifetime type="singleton"/>
      </register>
    </container>
</unity>
```

code:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer().LoadConfiguration();
```

Comment: And are both instances of Event_Class gonna be the same?

Comment: <typeAlias alias="singleton" type="Unity.Lifetime, Unity.Configuration"/>

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough the accepted solution didn't work for me... It would end up creating two singletons hehe, one per interface. What did the trick for me was first registering the type to have a lifetime of singleton and then adding the actual mappings without any lifetime. Like this:

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">

<alias alias="Event_Interface" type="Mynamespace.IEventService, MyAssembly"/>
<alias alias="EventService_Interface" type="Mynamespace.IEventServiceInformation, MyAssembly"/>
<alias alias="Event_Class" type="Mynamespace.EventService, MyAssembly"/>

<container>
  <register type="Event_Class"> 
    <lifetime type="singleton"/>
  </register>
  <register type="Event_Interface" mapTo="Event_Class"/>
  <register type="EventService_Interface" mapTo="Event_Class"/>
</container>
```

Comment: This also works for named registrations, simply add `name="name"` to all registration elements.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work with configuration files for unity yet, but according to the documentation it is

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <namespace name="MyApp.Implementations" />
    <assembly name="MyApp" />
    <container>
        <register type="IEventService" mapTo="EventService" />
        <register type="IEventServiceInformation" mapTo="EventService" />
    </container>
</unity>
```

Comment: you missed <lifetime type="singleton"/>