# Unity Container: Register two singletones which implement two interfaces one of which is common

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container, resolve, service-locator

I can't figure out how to do following with UnityContainer.

```
interface A { }
interface B { }
interface X { }
class ConcreteAX : A, X { }
class ConcreteBX : B, X { }
```

I need to register both concrete classes so as `ServiceLocator.ResolveAll<X>` should return both instances. Same time `Resolve<A>` and `Resolve<B>` should work as well. Moreover, **I must not instantiate them myself while registering services.**

If I use named registration for `X` to make `ResolveAll` work, then two instances of each of concrete classes are created. If I use named registration for all interfaces, then `Resolve<A>` and `Resolve<B>` does not work. If I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394650/unity-register-two-interfaces-as-one-singleton) approach then `ResolveAll` returns nothing.

How to do the trick with UnityContainer?

Comment: I don't see a (easey) possibility right now if you cannot instanciate the singeltons (I guess you could write your own LifetimeManager or use nested containers) before registration, but why don't you just make the values in the classes static - it won't matter if you get different instances then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the second (named) registration using `ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager` and `InjectionFactory` in which you resolve the default registration. For example:

```
unity.RegisterType<A, ConcreteAX>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
unity.RegisterType<B, ConcreteBX>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
unity.RegisterType<X, ConcreteAX>("AX", 
    new ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager(), 
    new InjectionFactory(u => u.Resolve<A>()));
unity.RegisterType<X, ConcreteBX>("BX", 
    new ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager(), 
    new InjectionFactory(u => u.Resolve<B>()));
```

Comment: +1 Nice solution, I tend to forget that Unity is a capable IoC container :). Maybe you can expand your sample with some code for the further visitors.